The training error and testing error is very similiar for linear regression model when using gradient descent
I had to implement gradient descent to learn the B0 and B1 for predicting a linear polynomial equation the program runs as expected but the plot shows that the training error and the testing error of the model is very similar.
Here is the following program:
import random

# Importing the numerical Python library
import numpy as np

# Importing matplotlib for plotting the graph
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Function to generate a dataset based on the input x
def datasetGenerator(x: int) -> int:
    return ((2 * x) - 3) + np.random.normal(0, 5)


# mean squared error calculation for comparing the actual y with the prediction
def meanSquaredError(y: float, y_pred: float) -> float:
    # summation of squares of all the y with y predictions divided by the length of y using the np.mean method
    # return np.mean((y - y_pred) ** 2)
    return np.mean((y - y_pred) ** 2)


def gradientDescent(
    X: list[float],
    Y: list[float],
    Y_pred: list[float],
    B0: float,
    B1: float,
    learningRate: float,
):
    # doe E by doe B0
    B0 -= learningRate * np.mean(-2 * (Y - Y_pred))
    # doe E by doe B1
    B1 -= learningRate * np.mean(-2 * (Y - Y_pred) * (X))
    return B0, B1


def betaCalculation(X: list[float], Y: list[float], n: int) -> int:
    # numpy array of X power 1 to 5
    Xtrans = [np.power(X, i) for i in range(n + 1)]

    # actual X values in form of X tranpose's transpose
    Xnew = np.transpose(Xtrans)

    # dot product of X transpose with X
    XTX = np.matmul(Xtrans, Xnew)

    # inverse of dot product of X Transpose with X
    XTXm1 = np.linalg.inv(XTX)

    # dot product of inverse of dot product of X transpose and X with X tranpose
    XTXinvintoXT = np.matmul(XTXm1, Xtrans)

    # Dot product of dot product of inverse of dot product of X transpose and X with X tranpose with Y
    Beta = np.matmul(XTXinvintoXT, Y)

    # array of beta elements
    return Beta


def optimalFit(
    B0: float,
    B1: float,
    X_train: list[float],
    Y_train: list[float],
    X_test: list[float],
    Y_test: list[float],
    learningRate,
) -> tuple[list[list[float]], list[float], list[int]]:
    flag = True
    Ynew = Y_train
    epsTrainArr = []
    epsTestArr = []
    epochsArr = []
    B = []
    epochs = 0

    while flag:
        # prediction of the model for previous B0 and B1
        Y_pred_train = B0 + B1 * X_train
        Y_pred_test = B0 + B1 * X_test

        # checking if the code converged or not
        flag = False if meanSquaredError(Ynew, Y_pred_train) <= 1e-6 else True

        # finding the error of the mean squared error
        eps_train = meanSquaredError(Y_train, Y_pred_train)
        eps_test = meanSquaredError(Y_test, Y_pred_test)

        # calculating new B0 and B1 using gradient descent
        B0, B1 = gradientDescent(X_train, Y_train, Y_pred_train, B0, B1, learningRate)
        B.append([B0, B1])
        Ynew = Y_pred_train

        # adding the epoch value to see how it converges
        epochs += 1

        # appending the arror onto the eps array it has eps until the model converges
        epsTrainArr.append(eps_train)
        epsTestArr.append(eps_test)

        # appending the apochs onto the epochs array it has epoch count until the model converges
        epochsArr.append(epochs)

    return B, epsTrainArr, epsTestArr, epochsArr


# gets executed when the file is executed
def main():
    # generating y values with the
    # Generating 100 evenly spaced numbers between -5 and 5
    # contains the whole population of data
    X_init = np.linspace(-5, 5, 1000)

    # Calling the datasetGenerator function to get y for every x in X
    Y_init = datasetGenerator(X_init)

    XYtup = []
    for i in range(len(X_init)):
        XYtup.append(tuple([X_init[i], Y_init[i]]))

    XYtup = np.array(XYtup)
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    rng.shuffle(XYtup)
    XYtup = XYtup.tolist()

    # getting the training dataset
    # The X array is sliced to get the training array, this is also the X^1 array
    X = np.array([XYtup[i][0] for i in range(len(X_init))])
    Y = np.array([XYtup[i][1] for i in range(len(X_init))])

    # Splitting the dataset into training, validation, and testing sets
    split_idx_train = int(X.shape[0] * 0.8)

    # creating the test and training part of the dataset
    train_data = random.sample(XYtup, split_idx_train)
    test_data = [i for i in XYtup if i not in train_data]

    X_train, Y_train = zip(*train_data)
    X_test, Y_test = zip(*test_data)

    X_train = np.array(X_train)
    Y_train = np.array(Y_train)

    X_test = np.array(X_test)
    Y_test = np.array(Y_test)

    B0 = np.random.normal(0, 1)
    B1 = np.random.normal(0, 1)
    # putting the B0 and B1 in a list
    B = [[B0, B1]]
    learningRate = 0.1

    B, epsTrainArr, epsTestArr, epochsarr = optimalFit(
        B0, B1, X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, learningRate
    )
    plt.plot(
        epochsarr,
        epsTrainArr,
        label=f"Epoch vs Training Error for learning rate: {learningRate}",
        c="r",
    )
    plt.plot(
        epochsarr,
        epsTestArr,
        label=f"Epoch vs Testing Error for learning rate: {learningRate}",
        c="b",
    )
    plt.title(
        "The epoch count vs the epsilon of the model for different learning rates"
    )
    # plotting with the x label as epochs
    plt.xlabel("Epochs")
    # plotting with the y label as error
    plt.ylabel("Error")
    # having a description for the graph to explain what it does
    plt.figtext(
        0.5,
        0.01,
        f"this plot represents how the mean squared error of the model decreases as the number of epoch increases for different learning rates",
        wrap=True,
        horizontalalignment="center",
        fontsize=10,
        bbox={"facecolor": "grey", "alpha": 0.3, "pad": 5},
    )
    # legends to explain which coloured line represents which learning rate
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    learningRate = 0.001
    while learningRate <= 0.1:
        B, epsTrainArr, epsTestArr, epochsarr = optimalFit(
            B0, B1, X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, learningRate
        )
        epochs = epochsarr[-1]

        # printing the Beta computed using gradient descent and closedform solution
        print(
            f"B0 and B1 after the model converges: {B[-1]} with error {epsTrainArr[-1]}"
        )
        print(f"B0 and B1 for closed form solution: {betaCalculation(X, Y, 1)}")

        # printing the epoch value to see how it converges
        print(
            f"number of epochs needed for convergence: {epochs} for learning rate: {learningRate}\n"
        )
        plt.plot(
            epochsarr[5:],
            epsTrainArr[5:],
            label=f"Epoch vs Error for learning rate: {learningRate}",
        )

        learningRate *= 10
    print(len(B))

    # setting the title of the graph to specify which axis has which variable and other things
    plt.title(
        "The epoch count vs the epsilon of the model for different learning rates"
    )
    # plotting with the x label as epochs
    plt.xlabel("Epochs")
    # plotting with the y label as error
    plt.ylabel("Error")
    # having a description for the graph to explain what it does
    plt.figtext(
        0.5,
        0.01,
        f"this plot represents how the mean squared error of the model decreases as the number of epoch increases for different learning rates",
        wrap=True,
        horizontalalignment="center",
        fontsize=10,
        bbox={"facecolor": "grey", "alpha": 0.3, "pad": 5},
    )
    # legends to explain which coloured line represents which learning rate
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

and here is the plot output
I expected the training error to be lower than testing error.
but in my graph the training error exceeds the testing error almost all the time which means there is an error in sampling.I have tried different sampling methods but have the same issue.
epoch vs Training error and epoch vs Testing error

Let's plot your X against your Y:
plt.scatter(X_init, Y_init)
plt.show()


This is just a straight line. If you have two points on this line, you can perfectly predict any points on this line.
Let's examine how you generate Y.
# Function to generate a dataset based on the input x
def datasetGenerator(x: int) -> int:
    return ((2 * x) - 3) + np.random.normal(0, 5)

This does a linear transformation to X, then adds some random noise. However, note that np.random.normal(0, 5) draws a single random sample. That random sample is then broadcast to the array. This means that the same random value is added to all values.
You can generate one random value per X value instead:
# Function to generate a dataset based on the input x
def datasetGenerator(x: int) -> int:
    return ((2 * x) - 3) + np.random.normal(0, 5, size=len(x))

This gives you a more realistic looking dataset.

This also makes your testing and training errors different.

Thanks for the solution, I knew there were some issues with the dataset generation I couldn't figure out what it was. This answer helped me get to the solution. I had to make some more changes for it to work though.

Here is the working code for anybody interested:
https://pastebin.com/DTFj7FZg
